# Not enough input arguments, accessing table data

Tags: matlab, csv

I am using 'readtable' for the first and believe this is an excellent way of accessing large data sets that contain mixed data types?

I am having problems plotting this data - my goal would be to plot the 'data.Var#' directly as this feels more elegant to me.

However, I am having problems plotting the data and would really appreciate some help. Below is some example code and I have also attached an equivalent data file.

```
clear
clc

data = readtable('TestTable.csv','HeaderLines',4,'ReadVariableNames',true);

plot(data.SomeX,data.SomeY)
```

Below is an import of the '.csv' file. This should just paste into Excel if required.

```
'00:00.4'   0
'00:00.5'   0
'00:01.0'   25.4700000000000
'00:01.5'   25.4700000000000
'00:02.0'   25.4800000000000
'00:02.5'   25.4800000000000
'00:03.0'   25.4800000000000
'00:03.5'   25.4800000000000
```

[Image of imported data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ23q.png)

n.b. I have updated this to include some comments

UPDATE- turns out I was being a bit stupid and trying to plot different data types together.

```
clear
clc

data = readtable('TestTable.csv','HeaderLines',4,'ReadVariableNames',true);

x1 = 1:1:length(y);

plot(x1,data.SomeY)
```

Maybe I should delete this question?

Comment: In the first case the second column is numeric and in the second case the second column is a string. Skip the headerline with the parameter `HeaderLines` and set `ReadVariableNames` to `True` in order to preserve the variable name.

Comment: Hi @obchardon I will update my original question to include your comments. Thank you

Comment: I think I got carried away with the idea of tables and what they can and can't do. Thanks for your help @obchardon

Comment: According to the [doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-X) `X` can be of type `single | double | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | categorical | datetime | duration` but not a `string`, so either convert your date string with `datenum` (and then use `datetick` to display the result) of use the `datetime` datatype.

Comment: Great, this is great information thanks you have helped me a great deal!